# Prove that the tangent $A$ and $B$ are perpendicular .

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convexity-inequality

Let $f(x)=x^x$ and $g(x)=\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{x}$ .Let $A$ be the tangent of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ and $B$ the tangent of $g(x)$ at $x=1$ . Then A and B are perpendicular .

### Proof without first derivative

Clearly since the equation $x^x=x$ have a unique solution which is $x=1$ we conclude that $y=x$ is a tangent of the function $f(x)$ using convexity and the three chord lemma .The same reasoning apply to the equation $\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{x}=2-x$ and using convexity conducts to $y=2-x$ is a tangent of the function $g(x)$ . Now it's easy to conclude .

So I think it's a problem with many solutions so feel free to share it !

Thanks in advance for all your advices comments and answers !

Comment: Your reasoning is cute.  I like it.  Nit picking, $(1/x)^x$ is neither convex or concave, so it's a little difficult to see why $y=2-x$ is tangent to $y=g(x)$ at (1,1).

Comment: @irchans We can say that there two derivatives one on the right and the other on the left and after see that we speak about the same mathematical object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=h$ and $g=1/h$.  Then $f=g\iff h^2(x)=1$.  Furthermore,
$$f'\cdot g'=h'\cdot(-1)\cdot\frac{1}{h^2}h'.$$
Thus the tangents in the point of intersection are perpendicular iff $(h'(x))^2=1.$